# Does turning off 'sync from iPhoto' remove my photos?

Tags: itunes, mac, photos.app

If I've downloaded my photos onto iPhoto and turn off 'sync from iPhoto' on iTunes, will I loose any photos on iPhoto?

Answer (score 1):

Turning off Sync iPhoto will remove any iPhoto images you put into your Photos Library on your phone, but will keep the images on your Mac.